# QPainterPath PyQt5 draw difficult figures

Tags: pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qpainterpath

Hellow. How can i draw smth like figure on pic using the qpainter path ? Does anybody have some code examples?

[image: i need to get smth like this]

Answer (score 0):

Bézier curve is a cubic line. Bézier curve in PyQt5 can be created with QPainterPath. A painter path is an object composed of a number of graphical building blocks, such as rectangles, ellipses, lines, and curves.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt5 tutorial 

This program draws a Bézier curve with 
QPainterPath.

Author: Jan Bodnar
Website: zetcode.com 
Last edited: August 2017
"""

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 380, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Bézier curve')
        self.show()


    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawBezierCurve(qp)
        qp.end()


    def drawBezierCurve(self, qp):

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(30, 30)
        path.cubicTo(30, 30, 200, 350, 350, 30)

        path.addEllipse(90, 30, 200, 70)          # +++

        qp.drawPath(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thx, but what about using painter path to draw difficult figures (composed of rectangles, circles and others), not the Bezier curve. I've red the docs, but didn't managed to do it bymyself ( i need some kind of a truncated ellipse, should i use this curve ?

Comment: Draw what you need. I added the ellipse.